# How To Format And Bind Multiple SimpleObjectProperties<LocalDate> To A Label?

Tags: kotlin, tornadofx

I am trying to create a calendar view in which there are events displayed with start and end times on one label. Something like:

```
2:30pm - 4:30pm
```

My model has a SimpleObjectProperty<LocalTime> for each of these times. I know that I could concatenate these by doing something like:

```
label(Bindings.concat(model.startTime, " - ", model.endTime))
```

But I would still need formatting for each time. Knowing how to do this would certainly help me in the future with other equally complex binding transformations. Or would it just be easier to attach listeners to each time property that would update the label text?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I found my own answer, but anyone can feel free to let me know if this is good practice or not.

```
root {
   ...
   val timeFormat = DateTimeFormatter.ofPattern("h:mma")
   label(stringBinding(model.startTime, model.endTime) {
               val startTime = model.startTime.value
               val endTime = model.endTime.value
               "${startTime.format(timeFormat)} - ${endTime.format(timeFormat)}"
           })
   ...
}
```

Comment: Yes, that's a valid way to do it, but an alternative would be to create that string binding in your model, so you would simply do `label(model.fromToTime)` in your UI code. Looks cleaner and promotes reuse.